# javascript randomly fails to sort items, no error

Tags: javascript, sorting, random, prestashop

For some reason Javascript stops working randomly.

Code that is dealing with height problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 

    /*setEqualHeight($("ul#product_list li"));*/
    //alert("some text");
    /*setEqual($("ul#product_list"));*/
    //var i = 2;
    //alert($('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i + 2) +')').height()); //this is correct way to get value*/
    var elements = $('ul#product_list li').length; //this is correct way to get value
    /*var liekana = elements % 3;
    elements = elements - liekana;
    alert(elements);*/
    for(var i = 1; i <= elements; i = i + 3)
    {
        var first = $('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i) +')').height();
        var second = $('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i + 1) +')').height();
        var third = $('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i + 2) +')').height();
        var tallest = 0;
        if (first > second)
            if (first > third)
            {
                tallest = first; 
            }
            else 
            {
                tallest = third;
            }
        else
            if (second > third)
            {
                tallest = second;
            }
            else
            {
                tallest = third;
            }
        $('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i) +')').height(tallest);
        $('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i + 1) +')').height(tallest);
        $('ul#product_list li:nth-child('+ (i + 2) +')').height(tallest);
        /*if (!third)
            alert("yra");*/
    }
});
```

Failing URL: http://piguskompiuteris.lt/6_asus
Normal render URL: http://piguskompiuteris.lt/16-lenovo

Any suggestions how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE 2. I have rewriten javascript code... I still get the same random errors, sometimes grid collapses. I am not sure what is the cause.

Possible causes:
1) Height attribute is too small and doesn't include height + padding + margin + border
2) There is something wrong with function placement (currently not in header) or calling it $(document).ready(function()

Comment: The pages you linked to are quite complex. Please tell us which feature on these pages uses the code above, what it does on the first and in which way it fails on the second.

Comment: They both use product-list.tpl from prestashop templates.
Javascript is embeded in template and is called every time product page is requested. Therefore both pages using same code, however sometimes it randomly fails and sometimes it is working.

Does it answers your question?

Comment: no, it doesn't. **Which feature** on the page doesn't work?

Comment: product grid, items should be all the same height as tallest row item. Sometimes script works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting script works.

To fix script use:

$(window).load(function() {});

Out instead of:

$(document).ready(function() {});

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site. And found this solution use it:

```
columns.height(tallestcolumn);
```

Replace above code with the following code:

```
columns.css("min-height", tallestcolumn+" !imporatant");
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have tried your suggested solution unfortunaley it doesn't work.
http://piguskompiuteris.lt/themes/default/img/fail2.jpg

Comment: @user2141587 I have updated the code check with that. this will work sure. I have change the `height` with `min-height` and this is working as I have checked. use it.

Comment: Made adjustments, still grid collapses, take a look yourself. :)

Comment: @user2141587 have you check the updated code of mine and change the height with min-height?

Comment: Yes, I've made the changes.

Comment: @user2141587 but on the site I am unable to find the updated code. There is not showing that you have use the min-height or height.

Comment: your current li is looks as `<li class="ajax_block_product last_item item">` but before it was as it is: <li class="ajax_block_product last_item item" style="min-height:337px">`. your js is not loaded properly. check have you ass the js and clear the cache of the site then use is.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

I have spotted another issue. This script compares all elements, and then takes the max height value.

I want to rewrite it so it goes by row of 3 elements, and if row has 2 or 1 item it doesn't break the grid.

I'll update post shortly

I am very grateful for your help :)))))))))))))